# How do you return Solr child objects and grandchild objects along with the parent?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to query Solr 8.1.1 (using the velocity UI (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/{core_name}/query), nothing fancy yet) and need to return the parent (Product), child (Module) and grandchild (Exercise) when querying the parent docs as one object rather than a flat list of docs.

I've imported my index using the DIH as below. Debugging output for the DIH import shows the *childDocuments* field and a structure I would expect, but querying the index only returns a flat structure.

Most sources suggest I add `fl=*,[child]` or `fl=*,[child childFilter=Depth:1]` or `[child parentFilter=Depth:0 childFilter=Depth:1]` (which I'm pretty sure only returns one extra level anyway) to my url or the fl field in the UI, but this seemingly has no effect.

My DIH config is as follows:

```
    <document name="productDocument">  
        <entity name="Product" query="SELECT p.*, '0' AS Depth FROM Solr.Product p">
            <field column="ProductId" name="ProductId" />
            <field column="Description" name="Description" />
            <field column="ProductCode" name="ProductCode" />
            <field column="ProductType" name="ProductType" />
            <field column="ProductLevel" name="ProductLevel" />
            <field column="LearningTime" name="LearningTime" />
            <field column="Vendor" name="Vendor" />
            <field column="Introduction" name="Introduction" />
            <field column="ReleasedDate" name="ReleasedDate" />
            <field column="MarketingRank" name="MarketingRank" />
            <field column="Price" name="Price" />
            <field column="Depth" name="Depth"/>
            <field column="QuestionCount" name="QuestionCount"/>
            <field column="PassMark" name="PassMark"/>
            <field column="IsActive" name="IsActive"/>
            <entity child="true" name="Module" query="SELECT m.*, '1' AS Depth FROM Solr.Module m WHERE m.ProductId='${Product.ProductId}'">
                <field column="ModuleId" name="ModuleId" />
                <field column="ProductId" name="ProductId" />
                <field column="Description" name="Description" />
                <field column="LearningTime" name="LearningTime" />
                <field column="Depth" name="Depth"/>
                <field column="Order" name="Order"/>
                <field column="IsActive" name="IsActive"/>
                <entity child="true" name="Exercise" query="SELECT e.*, '2' AS Depth, '${Product.ProductId}' AS ProductId FROM Solr.Exercise e WHERE e.ModuleId='${Module.ModuleId}'">
                    <field column="ExerciseId" name="ExerciseId" />
                    <field column="ModuleId" name="ModuleId" />
                    <field column="ProductId" name="ProductId" />
                    <field column="Description" name="Description" />
                    <field column="Depth" name="Depth"/>
                    <field column="Order" name="Order"/>
                    <field column="IsActive" name="IsActive"/>
                </entity>
            </entity>           
        </entity>  
    </document>
```

The relevant section from the managed-schema is as follows:

```
    <field name="ProductId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- docValues are enabled by default for long type so we don't need to index the version field  -->
    <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

    <!-- If you don't use child/nested documents, then you should remove the next two fields:  -->
    <!-- for nested documents (minimal; points to root document) -->
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
    <!-- for nested documents (relationship tracking) -->
    <field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" /><fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" />

    <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- Product / Root -->
    <field name="Description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" /> 
    <field name="ProductCode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="ProductType" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="ProductLevel" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="LearningTime" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="Vendor" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="Introduction" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="ReleasedDate" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="MarketingRank" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="Price" type="pfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="Order" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="QuestionCount" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
    <field name="PassMark" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
    <field name="IsActive" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false" />
```

I would expect the output from the query to match the DIH debug output and the DIH structure. Is what I need even possible? Any help is appreciated.